Sharing state with runes when assigning the value from async
I am a bit new to those stuff and not sure if my approach is wrong. I would like to have a class and the schemaData needs to be loaded from an async request.
But when I am getting the schemaData the state is not being updated after the updateSchema.
// SchemaManager.ts
export class SchemaManager {
    schemaData: SchemaData = $state<SchemaData>({});

    updateSchema(data: any) {
        this.schemaData = this.organizeSchemaData(data);
    }
}

const SCHEMA_KEY = Symbol("SCHEMA_DATA");

export function setSchemaState() {
    return setContext(SCHEMA_KEY, new SchemaManager());
}

export function getSchemaState() {
    return getContext<ReturnType<typeof setSchemaState>>(SCHEMA_KEY);
}

// layout.svelte
setSchemaState();
const schemaManager = getSchemaState();
onMount(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("/json-schema");
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        schemaJson = await response.json();

        schemaManager.updateSchema(schemaJson);
        // console.log(schemaManager.getType("OBJECT", "Query"));
    } catch (e) {
        error = e instanceof Error ? e.message : String(e);
        console.log("error", error);
    }
});

<!-- TextDecoderStream.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import { getSchemaState } from "$lib/utils/schemaToJsonUtils.svelte";
    const schemaManager = getSchemaState();
    const currentSchema = schemaManager.schemaData;
    console.log("schema", currentSchema);
</script>

the console.log here is only {} empty object, it doesnt get triggered after the updateSchema. I tried having my setSchemaState inside the onMount but it doesnt allow me to have context there.
Can you let me know what approach shuld i take.

This is not reactive:
const schemaManager = getSchemaState();
const currentSchema = schemaManager.schemaData;

The value is read once at time of execution.
If you want the value to update automatically, you need $derived:
const schemaManager = getSchemaState();
const currentSchema = $derived(schemaManager.schemaData);

To otherwise react to changes, the values would need to be accessed in an $effect, though if you just want to observe changes, use the development-only $inspect rune.
const schemaManager = getSchemaState();
const currentSchema = $derived(schemaManager.schemaData);
$inspect(currentSchema)

(console.log output can be a bit confusing because proxies used by the $state rune show the initial state of the object when logged.)

Thank you for that, $derived and $inspect it worked. And also console.log was one of the issues definetly, with inspect it does show updates.
